# On key press Id like to copy current content of my dgv cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

On key press Id like to copy current content of my dgv cell (for example value of col 5,cell 1) and paste it with the same column below defending on the loop i choose.

Below code doesnt work.please help.

```
private void dataGridView8_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView8.CurrentCell != null)
    {
        for (int i = 5; i < dataGridView8.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            i = dataGridView8.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Column 5 cell 1 or Row 5 cell 1? do you want to put this value to row below in the corresponding cell for all rows?

Comment: key press event is not working for grid view, i am using vs2010

Comment: hi adil,its col 5 row 1 yes i want to put the value with all rows below of the corresponding cell when i hit enter on my key board.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView8.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView8.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Purchase Order Empty!");
                    return;
                }
                else if (dataGridView8.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView8.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
                }

Comment: above code also doesnt work